# Picking a reflected Type from a list to which a runtime object can be assigned

Tags: scala, reflection

Say I have a list of `Type` instances (which refer to classes!), and a runtime object of unknown type. Find the/a type of which the object is sub type.

```
import reflect.runtime.universe._

// obj _required_ to be of type Any, no compile time type available
def find(tps: List[Type], obj: Any): Option[Type] = ???
```

Such that

```
sealed trait Gender
case object Male   extends Gender
case object Female extends Gender
case object Other  extends Gender

val tps = List(typeOf[Male.type], typeOf[Female.type], typeOf[Other.type])
assert(find(tps, Other).get =:= typeOf[Other.type])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get the `Type` or the correspondent `Class` from the runtime mirror, and then just compare them:

```
def find(tps: List[Type], obj: Any): Option[Type] = {
  val mirror = runtimeMirror(this.getClass.getClassLoader)
  val tpe = mirror.classSymbol(obj.getClass).toType

  tps find (tpe <:< _)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following seems correct, although I guess it will fail with higher kinded types:

```
import reflect.runtime.universe._
import reflect.runtime.{currentMirror => cm}

def find(tps: List[Type], obj: Any): Option[Type] = {
  val objClass = obj.getClass
  val objType  = cm.classSymbol(objClass).toType
  tps find (objType <:< _)
}
```